# Not getting book data from openlibrary.org api

Tags: javascript, ajax, api

I want to get book data from openlibrary.org api. I have tried some code given below,but i don't get any data.I am a newbie, learning to code,please help me in this regard.

```js
var isbn = $('.book').data('isbn');

$.ajax({
  dataType: 'json',
  url: 'http://openlibrary.org/api/books?bibkeys=ISBN:' + isbn + '&jscmd=details&format=json',
  success: handleResponse
});

function handleResponse(response) {
  //    alert(JSON.stringify(response));
  var isbnObj = 'ISBN:' + isbn;
  var detail = response.isbnObj;

  $.each(detail.details, function(i, datas) {

    var title = datas.title,
      author = datas.authors[0].name;

    $('.title').text(title);
    $('.author').text(author);

  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <section class="media book showcase" data-isbn="0553283685">
    <header>
      <h3 class="title"></h3>
      <h4 class="author"></h4>
    </header>



  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var keyData = "0553283685";
$.ajax({
  url: "https://openlibrary.org/api/books?bibkeys=ISBN:" + keyData + "&jscmd=details&callback=mycallback",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  success: function(data) {
    var getData = data["ISBN:" + keyData];
    var title = getData.details.title,
      author = getData.details.authors[0].name;
    $('.title').text(title);
    $('.author').text(author);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <section class="media book showcase" data-isbn="0553283685">
    <header>
      <h3 class="title"></h3>
      <h4 class="author"></h4>
    </header>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is the response for http://openlibrary.org/api/books?bibkeys=ISBN:0553283685&jscmd=details&format=json

```
{
  "ISBN:0553283685": {
    ...
  }
}
```

```
var isbnObj = 'ISBN:' + isbn; // isbn is '0553283685'
var detail = response.isbnObj;
```

What you are trying to achieve with the above two lines of code is to access the value with the property "ISBN:0553283685", however in javascript, this will be interpreted as trying to access value with the property `isbnObj` literally. Since `response` does not have a property `isbnObj`, `detail` will be `undefined` and subsequently at `detail.details` will result in the error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'details' of undefined:

To use a variable to access object's property, you need to use the `object[keyVariable]` notation.

To illustrate this with an example,

```
var sampleObject = {
  name: "123",
};
var key = "name";

console.log(sampleObject.name); // "123"
console.log(sampleObject['name']); // "123"

console.log(sampleObject.key); // undefined
console.log(sampleObject['key']); // undefined

console.log(sampleObject[key]); // "123"
```

Comment: @Justicetaylor If the answer is helpful, please upvote it so that other users who are facing the same issue can learn.

Comment: i upvoted it, a pop up shows that "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."